# Laravel collection filter by nested keys

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

Using [Laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections) (I can't use DB queries), I need to filter out some users based on their account's permissions, I have the following relationships:

```
User belongsTo an Account
Account belongsToMany Permissions
```

I tried to use the dot notation:

```php
$users->whereIn('account.permissions.id', $arrayOfpermissions)

// I also tried the * keyword but no luck
$users->whereIn('account.permissions.*.id', $arrayOfPermissions)
```

Is there a Laravel function for this case, if not how can I do it **efficiently**?

Answer (score 0):

Try [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) filter in laravel

```
$permissions = User::whereHas('account.permissions', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->whereIn('account.permissions.id', $arrayOfpermissions);
})->get();
```

Comment: As I said, I can't use DB queries.